# How to exclude months from Ruby on Rails `date_select` form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, helper

I want to have a `date_select` to shoy me only months from now on.

So if we're on March it'd only show:

```
- March
- April
- May
- June
- July
- August
- September
- October
- November
- December
```

Now i have this:

```
f.date_select :meeting_date,{:order=>[:month,:day]}
```

Is there something like `start_month` like there's a `start_year` attribute to this helper? so i can use something like:

```
f.date_select :meeting_date,{:start_month=>Time.now.month,:order=>[:month,:day]}
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  What meaningful choices would you have on new years eve?

Comment: It'd be saving for year `Time.now.year' the only thing i want to do is prevent the client to schedule an appointment in past months

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a date_select? Why not simply use a normal select if you are only selecting months?

Comment: I want this to be maintenance free and i want this to automatically exclude past months is there any helper o should i do this coding by hand ?

Comment: I would recommend doing it by hand @Sam has the closest solution it seems. Since you aren't really using a date per-se it's easier to do this coding on your own so you have the proper control over it. I would recommend considering what your select will look like in December though.

Comment: Guess I'm doing it by hand, many thanks to y'all !

Answer (score 2):

If you want just months then you can make custom helpers.

Make a months constant in `config/initializers/constants.rb`

```
MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Marh'] #etc...
```

If you have a from with `|f|` you can have a month builder:

```
def month_select_builder(f, attr)
    f.select attr.symbolize, options_for_select(MONTHS)
end
```

If you just have a form_tag with no builder then:

```
def month_select(attr)
    select_tag attr.symbolize, options_for_select(MONTHS)
end
```

The `attr` is the name of the field on your models which is `:meeting_date`. Just pass that as a string.

Comment: this one is goo but isn't it just like `select_month` helper? ?

Answer (score -1):

```
months = %w(Jan Feb March ... )
f.date_select :meeting_date, :use_month_names => months[(Date.today.month - 1)..-1]
```

but it will insert blanks items, because `:use_month_names` expects Array with 12 items. To remove them you should write your own `date_select` helper

Comment: Why would i want blank items